# Remove spreadsheet formatting in rich text box

Tags: c#, winforms

I want to copy and paste some rows from MS Excel to a richTextBox in my C# Winforms app. The user will press CTRL+V on the keyboard and the Excel grid lines show up. How can i make sure the pasted content will only show up as Text?#

This does not seem to work:

```
private void richTextBox1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Control == true && e.KeyCode == Keys.V)
    {
        e.Handled = true;
        string st = Clipboard.GetText();
        richTextBox1.Text = st;
    }
}
```

I cannot use a textbox as my code looks like this:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    richTextBox2.Clear();
    richTextBox2.Focus();

    string strValues;
    strValues = richTextBox1.Text;

    var textInEachLine = richTextBox1.Text.Split(new string[] { "\n" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
    string whereClause = string.Join("', '", textInEachLine).ToString();
    richTextBox2.AppendText(" IN ( '" + whereClause + "')");
}
```

Comment: One solution might be to use `textbox` with `multiline` option set to true instead of `richtextbox`

Comment: Updated my question with my code. I cannot use a textbox as I use a string array. Unless you can rewrite it and show me

Comment: For me the code you provided is working, the problem must be somewhere else. Are there any more events on this `richtextbox`?

Comment: When you say its working did you copy the cells from Excel and try to paste it? if you see gridlines, then its not working...

Comment: Believe me, I dont see any grid lines. So there are no more events on this richtextbox right?

Comment: No more events on the richtextbox...

Comment: You must be doing something different to me.. I am pasting my cells from Excel and it DOES show the grid lines in the rich text box... show me an image of what you see?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/45541/discussion-between-marek-and-pricecheaperton)

Answer (score 1):

A better solution was to convert the richTextBox to a multi line textbox.

Answer (score 0):

Try This Code

```
 private void richTextBox1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.KeyCode == Keys.V && e.Modifiers == Keys.Control)
            {
                e.Handled = true;
                string st = Clipboard.GetText();
                richTextBox1.Text = st;
            }
            base.OnKeyDown(e);
        }



 private void richTextBox1_PreviewKeyDown(object sender, PreviewKeyDownEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Control == true && e.KeyCode == Keys.V) { e.IsInputKey = true; }
    }
```

Comment: does not work... i still get the pasted grids from excel

Answer (score 0):

I have looked around for a better answer to this for a while. I have come up with my own solution as I cannot get rid of the RichTextBox in the application I am supporting. I wrote up a form app to view the raw RTF data and pasted some cells in from excel.
The blank TextBox yielded...

> {\rtf1\ansi\ansicpg1252\deff0\deflang1033{\fonttbl{\f0\fnil Calibri;}}
>   \viewkind4\uc1\pard\f0\fs22\par
>   }

When pasting in a few cells with some colored text it displayed...

> {\rtf1\ansi\ansicpg1252\deff0\deflang1033{\fonttbl{\f0\fnil Calibri;}}
>   {\colortbl ;\red255\green0\blue0;\red0\green0\blue0;}
>   \viewkind4\uc1\trowd\trgaph30\trleft-30\cellx1002\cellx2034\pard\intbl\cf1\f0\fs22 good text\cell\cf2 good text\cell\row
>   \intbl good text\cell\cf1 good text\cell\row
>   \pard\cf0\par
>   }

I found that removing the '\cell' or \cellx####' and returning the text to another RichTextBox resulted in all related formatting being removed. It seems the RichTextBox will strip invalid formatting.
With this this, I wrote the following method to be executed before pasting text into a RichTextBox.

```
private void CleanClipboardText()
    {
        string cleaned = Clipboard.GetText(TextDataFormat.Rtf);
        if (cleaned != null & cleaned != String.Empty)
        {
            Regex regex = new Regex(@"\\cellx\d{4}?");
            cleaned = regex.Replace(cleaned, " ");
            regex = new Regex(@"\\cell");
            cleaned = regex.Replace(cleaned, " ");
            Clipboard.SetText(cleaned, TextDataFormat.Rtf);
        }
    }
```

And this event for the "KeyDown" event.

```
private void RTB_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Control && e.KeyCode == Keys.V)
        {
            RichTextBox rtb = sender as RichTextBox;
            e.Handled = true;
            CleanClipboardText();
            rtb.Paste();
        }
    }
```

I used `.Paste();` as I do not want to overwrite the entire box's text as `richTextBox1.Text = st;` will. However, if you wanted to, you may want have the CleanClipboardText method return a string of the rtf data and then set the `RichTextBox.Rtf` instead.